# live tiles with background agent

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I want to create some live tiles for my app. And I am creating this live tile by writable bitmap using UIElemnt of page. And I want To make these tiles on periodic task and Its separate project. I have reference of that project in my main project where all views exist. But in my background scheduling project, I Want to access the main project view to access to UIelement to make live tile with writable bitmap. I am unable to access as its don't have reference of that project. And When ever i want to add that it says you cant add reference due to circular dependency.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to change the way you've organized your solution. Create a third project and reference it from the main project and from the background agent's project. Then move all the shared code and views in that new project.